# How do I tie a bowline knot?

Tags: ropes, knots, bowline-knots

Bowline knots are among the most commonly used knots across many different outdoor activities. It is used to create a fixed loop at the end of a line, while still being easy to tie and untie.

How would I tie a bowline knot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are good knots to know for camping and backpacking?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-are-good-knots-to-know-for-camping-and-backpacking)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is nice site with animation: http://www.apparent-wind.com/knots/bowline/

[image: Bowline knot]

Comment: This is the proper "inside tail" bowline, beware of the improper "outside tail" which is not a strong as the inside, and more prone to slipping.

Comment: To prevent slipping, you can make a couple half-hitches with the tail.

Comment: And for critical loads, and slippery rope, you should definitely be careful about slipping. For everyday use, I don't worry which way the tail ends up, and it's fine.

Comment: The rabbit goes through the hole, around the tree, and back down.

Comment: sorry kevin bolands don't slip. and a half hitch is not a preferred stopper knot. it is one of the few knots  you can use on amsteel.