# Quick release knot for attaching kit

Tags: gear, backpacking, knots

I'm currently using a double fisherman's bend to tie my kit together but it's a bit fiddly to take apart. Is there a better knot for the task? [image: double fish bend]

Comment: Do you need anything else than being quick-release?

Comment: @Roflo Ideally I want a single knot to hold this stuff together, not a separate knot at each end

Comment: What kind of objects will you be securing?  Personally, I prefer no-fuss carabiners for most gear.

Comment: @Quinto small items, compass, fire tin, etc - in the photo are the alternative settings for my walking sticks.. I may use carabiners in the future but like the idea of using what I have, plus I can swap it out for Firecord which I like as you can never have too little tinder!

Comment: Are you able to undo the green and black band at the top, or is it a loop that can't be opened up? That makes a big difference in the types of knots you can use.

Comment: @BenCrowell the loop is fixed - I can't open it up

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Girth Hitch

I think the knot you're using is appropriate if the idea is not to lose your kit, another knot may run you the risk of losing something because it came untied without your blessing.

If you're using cheap cord, then don't bother with the knot if it's giving you grief, just cut it at the knot, your cord will get shorter each time,  but it still usable for a couple cuts.

If you want to be able to attach something to your bag or belt quickly without fiddling with your knots, then I recommend simply **girth hitching** it:

[image]

Keep your loop tied to whatever with a double fishermans, then you can girth hitch it to practically anything as long as you can fit the loop around. In the image above I tied the cord around my strap, then passed a loop through the basket and folded it back around; only takes a second. You could even girth hitch both ends, then you don't have to tie cord around everything, just keep a bunch of tied loops, this makes it easy to use with a small carabiner too.

Comment: This works if he can open op the loop at the top that's being tied in to. I've asked the OP to clarify the question.

Comment: If the loop at the top doesn't open, you could make a slightly longer loop and girth hitch at the top as well. Using lighter cord would make it neater - the cord illustrated is surely overkill for this application?

Comment: @Tullochgorum The loop at top doesn't need to open, I already mention in my answer that girth hitching both ends could be an option, or you can use a small carabiner instead of a second girth hitch. And yes, the cord may be bigger than it needs to be in this picture, but that's the size cord I had.

Comment: @ShemSeger thanks! This works great, the double fishermans around the loop on my pack keeps everything secure and the girth hitch is quick to untie and retie

Answer (score 5):

The [bowline knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowline)

> form a fixed loop at the end of a rope. It has the virtues of being both easy to tie and untie; most notably, it is easy to untie after being subjected to a load.

See [How do I tie a bowline knot?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/432/how-do-i-tie-a-bowline-knot)

Comment: Thanks, would you suggest a bowline on each end of the cord?

Comment: I don't understand this answer. For the situation shown in the OP's photo, how would the bowline version work? See http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3798/how-safe-is-the-bowline-knot-in-different-situations

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes that you're trying to attach something to a loop (the black and green band in your photo) that you can't open up. If you can open up the loop, then see ShemSeger's answer.

It depends on how quickly you need it to release, and how important it is to you for it to stay secure.

A secure knot that is pretty easy to untie, even after it has been loaded, is the [offset overhand knot](http://www.animatedknots.com/flatoverhand/#ScrollPoint). I have had my keys in a loop of cord tied with an offset overhand, and after a year or two, the knot is still there. For good security, make sure to leave long tails, and dress and tighten the knot carefully.

If it's important to you to be able to release the knot very quickly, you could use a [slipped square knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_knot), i.e., the one you use to tie your shoes.