# How do I tie a stopper knot?

Tags: knots, climbing

A stopper knot is often used to prevent rope from unexpectedly going throu some hole, such as a belay device.

How would I tie a stopper knot?

Comment: See this question: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-are-good-knots-to-know-for-camping-and-backpacking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A stopper knot is not a specific knot, but a technique fo preventing a rope from sliding through a loop or hole. Common knots used for a stopper knot are:

[Overhand knot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhand_knot)

[Double overhand knot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_overhand_knot)

[Figure-of-eight knot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure-eight_knot_%28ropes%29)

[Stevedore knot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stevedore_knot)

[Ashley's stopper knot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashley%27s_stopper_knot)

Comment: Figure-8 is the most common stopper knot on a boat, but double overhand knot is probably a good choice for a newbie, because it's very easy to learn. Single overhand knot has a tendency to jam, so it's less desirable than the others.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a figure-eight knot, because if it is weighted you can still untie it. There are lots of knots to use, but figure-eights are the most common for this reason.

[Figure-eight - animated example](http://www.animatedknots.com/fig8_/index.php?LogoImage=LogoGrog.jpg&Website=www.animatedknots.com)