# What are different knots named in English?

Tags: knots

As English isn't my first language, I don't know the English words for different knots. Any translator fails on this part too.

Can someone point me to a source?

**edit: Please also describe synonyms and who uses those. Backpackers or climbers may use different names than sailors.**

Comment: Closed because this is basically just cut and paste of a good answer to another question.  I see where you are going, but perhaps we should do this in the blog.

Comment: Even in the blog I think it would be useful, not just with the names in English but go ahead and put other languages there too.

Comment: @RussellSteen: I would contribute the Danish names of the knots :) but why can't this be a simple question with one big wiki answer? It would be immensely useful to non-native English speakers like me to have this information searchable within the SE site -- not just forgotten in some past blog post.

Comment: Closed but it's still being voted up. Wonder why that is.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun -- Reopened, please contribute those names :)

Answer (score 8):

It is better not to link to outside sources as they can disappear. Linking within SE would be safe(r).

**Bowline Knot**
[Example for displaying translations]
Deustch (German) - Palstek

[image: Bowline Knot]

**Double Overhand Knot**

[image: Double Overhand Knot]

**Noose (or Hangman's Knot)**

[image: Noose (or Hangman's Knot)]

**Slip Knot**

[image: Slip Knot]

**Double Fisherman's Knot**

[image: Double Fisherman's Knot]

**Fortified Square Knot**

[image: Fortified Square Knot]

**Grapevine Knot**

[image: Grapevine Knot]

**Clove Hitch**

[image: Clove Hitch]

**Prusik Knot**

[image: Prusik Knot]

**Chain Sennit**

[image: Chain Sennit]

sources: '[What are good knots to know for camping and backpacking?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/73/741)'

Comment: Kudo's. I wanted to add that all the important knots for climbing are listed here.

Comment: Grapevine and double fisherman's are the same, no?

Answer (score 3):

There is a knot app for iOS and Android called Knots 3D that has knot names and their synonyms listed for English, Dutch, French, German, Italian, Korean, Russian and Spanish.  There are 87 knots in the app. More knots and languages are mentioned for future releases. The list of knots is here:

[English](http://nynix.com/knot-list/)

[Deutsch](http://nynix.com/knot-list/german-knot-names/)

[Nederlands](http://nynix.com/knot-list/dutch-knot-names/)

[Français](http://nynix.com/knot-list/french-knot-names/)

[Italiano](http://nynix.com/knot-list/italian-knot-names/)

[한국어](http://nynix.com/knot-list/korean-knot-names/)

[Pусский](http://nynix.com/knot-list/russian-knot-names/)

[Español](http://nynix.com/knot-list/spanish-knot-list/)