# How to tie an EBSB bowline?

Tags: climbing, knots, bowline-knots

According to [the most comprehensive reference](http://www.paci.com.au/downloads_public/knots/Bowlines_Analysis.pdf) ever written on bowlines, the EBSB bowline (which is a variation of another variation, called the EBDB bowline, together with a sort of Yosemite finish) is probably the safest easily undone tie-in knot for climbing. It looks like this:

[image: picture of bowline]

I can modify my EBDB bowline until it looks exactly like this knot. I'm pretty sure it's the very same, but I want to be over-sure. I can't find a reference that teaches to tie this knot step by step anywhere. Can someone help?

Comment: It takes 59 pages to get to a selection of the 4 most suitable 'creations' (authors term) and why they are superior in every way to the Fig 8. For the author, who obviously enjoys his deep knowledge of knots, I have no doubt they are superior.  I taught climbing for 10 year, I have doubts anything more complex than a Fig8 can safely be called safe in a public forum.

Comment: @Liam your answer is not about the EBSB bowline. There is a step where the rope must be passed inside two loops instead of one, and I want to be sure I'm passing it correctly.

Comment: @mattnz criticising the bowline is mainstream. Many people keep saying it is a hard to inspect knot, or that it slips, etc. These are just not true. Tying in with a simple bowline with a double fisherman as a finish is failproof. Ask any sailor. The reason to use a bowline variation with a tripled rope passing in the working loop is to minimise wearing due to hard falling and keep the rope intact, and the reason to use a Yosemite finish is to secure the knot tight. You don't like the knot, you don't use it. I can remember at least two serious accidents related to using the fig8.

Comment: @Liam I have absolutely no idea what those letters mean.

Comment: @QuantumBrick: My observation is not criticizing the Bowline. Its making a comment about the amount of effort it takes o become proficient in knots. A climber can go a very long way on 3 or 4 simple and reliable knots, and a Bowline is just not one of them

Comment: EBSB - End Bound Single Bowline
EBDB - End Bound Double Bowline

Comment: Brief update: I have been using the EBSB for the past three years now, and am alive enough to write this comment. I have started a small cult of around 5 or 6 people that are only using the EBSB for everything, including Patagonian climbing, trad, aid, single ropes, double ropes, twin ropes, no ropes. It's beautiful. I love it. Makes my day brighter.

Comment: @QuantumBrick: *I can remember at least two serious accidents related to using the fig8.* That's interesting, can you point us to information? Was this written up in, e.g., Accidents in North American Climbing?

Comment: @BenCrowell Not at all. They happened within my group of friends.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just needed to look a little farther on the PACI site for a step by step instuction on how to do the EBSB.

Check out [this pdf](http://www.paci.com.au/downloads_public/knots/S-Knots.pdf) on page 37 - pw *Copyright*
http://www.paci.com.au/knots.php

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I made a video about it like 2 years ago:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeU8x7OmxoQ

With a FPV of tying the knot.

Also be noted that the bowline paper has been updated and there's one more variation in there that is safe for climbing called "Harry Butlers Yosemite Bowline" which has been my default go-to lead climbing knot for the past 2 years, i recommend it over the ESBS since its a bit simpler to tie and inspect. Plus you end with no tail on the working end of the rope which helps when clipping.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2qnH06SVfs

Video of said knot but in spanish although you can follow up as well