# What is a "Post Eye Tiable" (PET) knot?

Tags: knots

In an answer on a question about bowlines the following statement is made by @MarkG:

> All 'Bowlines' have the advantage of being Post Eye Tiable (PET) and totally jam resistant.

https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/22084/3602

What is a "Post Eye Tiable" knot or equivalently, what makes a knot "Post Eye Tiable"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Post eye tiable means that the rope is passed through the eye or harness before any any part of the knot is tied.

This is in contrast to a rethreaded figure of eight which has to be partially tied, the first figure of eight, before the end is passed through the harness or other eye that the rope is being attached to.

Comment: So "Post" here means "After", and the phrase is parsed as "tiable after passing through the eye".

Comment: OP quotes that being `PET` is an advantage. Do you agree, and if yes could you outline why this is an advantage?

Comment: @fgysin, I consider it slightly more convenient but anything more than that I think would be entirely an opinion so not really suitable for the format.

Comment: At least in Germany, they teach only the figure of 8 knot to beginning climbers on courses, for the reason that even a beginner should be able to notice if one hasn't been tied properly. I guess from a practical point of view that outweighs any advantage/disadvantage of PET.

Comment: @fgysinreinstateMonica if the loop is very long, it is convenient that you do not have to wire so much cord for the initial knot before forming the loop.